# Get the last Sunday of the Month

Tags: ruby, chronic

I'm using Chronic to get the last Sunday of the month of any given year.  It will gladly give me the *n*‌th Sunday, but not the last.

This works, but is not what I need:

```
Chronic.parse('4th sunday in march', :now => Time.local(2015,1,1))
```

This is what I need, but doesn't work:

```
Chronic.parse('last sunday in march', :now => Time.local(2015,1,1))
```

Is there any way around this apparent limitation?

***UPDATE***:  I'm upvoting the two answers below because they're both good, but I've already implemented this in "pure Ruby" (in 2 lines of code, besides the `require 'date'` line), but I'm trying to demonstrate to management that Ruby is the right language to use to replace a Java codebase that is going away (and which had dozens of lines of code to compute this), and I told one manager that I probably could do it in one line of Ruby, and it would be readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: A pretty cheesy idea, but you could start at the first day of April and then just keep walking backwards in a loop of "yesterday" and break out when you get the first Sunday...

Comment: @aardvarkk just implemented that idea while you wrote your comment :)

Comment: @aardvarkk: For that matter, you can write `Chronic.parse('1 week before 1st sunday in april')`.

Comment: @ruakh: I would have suggested you make that an answer, because I would have accepted it, but it returns `nil`.

Comment: @iconoclast: Oops, sorry. The documentation gives the example `7 hours before tomorrow at noon`, so I assumed the `[interval] before [...]` notation would work more generally. My bad.

Comment: @ruakh: I think you've uncovered yet another limitation of Chronic... I think we need to submit patches to fix these!  :)

Comment: About your update: You can (or may) write this with `Chronic` in a single line, because you just call a function. However, using that argument you are basically saying that you can call a ruby function with a single line of code. `Chronic` probably need more than one line to implement this ;)

Comment: @tessi Yes I realize it's not an apples-to-apples comparison, but I'm looking for a way to dramatize to management the fact that Ruby is *clean*, *readable*, and *concise*.  A single line of Ruby to replace a mountain of Java can do that.  It's a single line of *our code* (they're paranoid about the supposed cost of Rubyists), so as long as it uses a well-maintained library, I think it's still a reasonable point to make.

Comment: @iconoclast I am counting three one-line solutions now (2 of them without a gem). I hope this (and the feedback you get here from other devs) can convince your management :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, and is as readable as I can get:

```
Chronic.parse('last sunday', now: Date.new(year,3,31))
```

Thanks to Ismael Abreu for the idea to just parse 'last sunday' and control the rest via the `:now` option.

UPDATE: Please also upvote Ismael's answer.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it fails if the last day of month is a sunday. `Chronic.parse('last sunday', now: Date.new(2017,12,31))`

Comment: From my previous comment, if you know the end of the month, just add 1 day: `Chronic.parse('last sunday', now: Date.new(2017,12,31)+1)`

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure about `Chronic` (I haven't heared about it before), but we can implement this in pure ruby :)

```
##
# returns a Date object being the last sunday of the given month/year
# month: integer between 1 and 12
def last_sunday(month,year)
  # get the last day of the month
  date = Date.new year, month, -1
  #subtract number of days we are ahead of sunday
  date -= date.wday
end
```

The `last_sunday` method can be used like this:

```
last_sunday 07, 2013
#=> #<Date: 2013-07-28 ((2456502j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Rather than `while date.wday != 0` `date -= 1` `end`, why not just `date -= date.wday`?

Comment: `(d = Date.new(2013, 7, -1)) - d.wday` would be the one line version

Comment: Thanks @steenslag - I am not sure if this is more readable (=maintainable), but the OP wished one-line solutions - so this is great :)

Comment: Hmm... I liked the 2 line version better.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the update in your question, I tried to come up with another answer using only a single line of ruby code (without using gems). How about this one?

```
##
# returns a Date object being the last sunday of the given month/year
# month: integer between 1 and 12
def last_sunday(month,year)
  # get the last day of the month, go back until we have a sunday
  Date.new(year, month, -1).downto(0).find(&:sunday?)
end

last_sunday 07, 2013
#=> #<Date: 2013-07-28 ((2456502j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: quite brilliant, but I'm not going to be able to convince them that a non-Rubyist will be able to maintain this, and (e.g.) change it to "first monday in January" if the need arises.

Comment: Let non-Rubyists maintain (more than a couple of lines of) ruby code is like [parsing HTML using regexes. It's like "asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#answer-1733489)

Comment: Brilliant comparison.  But you see what I'm up against.  :)

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
Chronic.parse('last sunday', now: Chronic.parse('last day of march'))
```

Comment: Nice idea to use Chronic to get `:now`, but this doesn't work.  First of all Chronic parses `last day of march` as `2013-03-01 12:00:00 -0500`, and secondly, I still need to specify an arbitrary year.  The second problem is solved by passing a `:now` value to the embedded Chronic expression.

Comment: You could also set the year with Chronic. And I just sent a pull request to be able to pass a string for the :now option https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/pull/199

Comment: so one could do `Chronic.parse('last sunday', now: '31 march, 2015')`

Comment: Yes, that will be a big improvement when they accept your pull request.  It's ironic that a library whose whole point is to parse strings to interpret dates won't do that on one of its own parameters.

Comment: Well, maybe it's because no one else needed it. I guess you know upfront the date for the now. I guess this is a special case, but I think it looks great just passing a string.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but you could simply try the 5th or 4th in that order:

```
d = [5,4].each do |i| 
  try = Chronic.parse("#{i}th sunday in march", :now => Time.local(2015,1,1))
  break try unless try.nil?
end
 => Sun Mar 29 12:30:00 +0100 2015

d = [5,4].each do |i| 
  try = Chronic.parse("#{i}th sunday in april", :now => Time.local(2015,1,1))
  break try unless try.nil?
end
 => Sun Apr 26 12:00:00 +0100 2015
```